# How to show a video preview in Twilio RTC React Native plugin

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-video

Using this react native plugin:

https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc

All working great, except that I'd like to display the user's local video preview to themselves before connecting to a room. However I can't seem to get the local preview (self-view) to show up until we actually connect to a room.

Can we start the video without connecting to a room?